# python 3.6 *logging modul error* UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters

Tags: python-3.x, logging, encoding, character-encoding, error-logging

On Windows 10 the logging module send this error (using scrapy)

```
# --- Logging error ---
...
# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 175-176: character maps to <undefined>
```

<s>I have read that I should add `encoding='utf-8'` but I did not find how I could add it in the code below.</s> *EDIT: According to [the tuto](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#log-encoding) it isnt needed.*

```
configure_logging(install_root_handler=False) #override default log settings
logging.basicConfig(
    filename='logfile.log',
    format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
    datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M',
    level=logging.INFO #CRITICAL ERROR WARNING  INFO    DEBUG    NOTSET 
)
```

I found many questions on the topics, but mostly on python 2 (or [not related to the logging module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43681633/1486850)). And the logging tutorial don't even talk about utf-8. (Notice that I can print UTF8 characters without any problem. The problem only occur with the logging module)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'm not using `Scrapy` but I ran into the same issue with vanilla Python 3.6 logging of not being able to write UTF-8 characters via `logging` to a file (console worked just fine).

Based on [this comment](https://github.com/KBNLresearch/iromlab/issues/55#issuecomment-300222928) I added `'utf-8'` to my `FileHandler` initialization.  I'm configuring logging via an INI file so it looks like this:

```
[handler_file]
class = FileHandler
args = (r'log.txt', 'a', 'utf-8')
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic
```

To use `logging.basicConfig()` I think that you should be able to do the following:

```
configure_logging(install_root_handler=False) #override default log settings
logging.basicConfig(
    handlers=[logging.FileHandler('logfile.log', 'w', 'utf-8')],
    format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
    datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M',
    level=logging.INFO #CRITICAL ERROR WARNING  INFO    DEBUG    NOTSET 
)
```

Comment: The answer with `logging.basicConfig()` doesn't work for me.

Comment: @SomJura, can you be a little more specific?  I just tried it on Python 3.8 and it seemed to work (I did skip the `configure_logging()` call).

Comment: It seems that it didn't work because I was using `import logging`, which is not necessay anymore with newer versions of Python.

Comment: Is it possible in windows?
Facing the same issue, I have tried the above solution but it's not working. I'm using Python 3.8.10. I tried removing the import statement, 'import logging', but that's causing errors.
'NameError: name 'logging' is not defined'

Comment: @Abhi, I initially had this problem in Windows so it should work in Windows.  What error are you having?  Reviewing the second `logging.basicConfig()` example, I'm not sure what that first line with `configure_logging()` is doing there, what if you delete that?

You will need `import logging`.

Comment: @smsearcy the error is resolved by upgrading Python version to 3.9, I saw this https://bugs.python.org/issue37111, and the fix was in Python 3.9.