# Python logger exception to file

Tags: python, exception, logging

I use [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html). The logger writes to file only. (and not to standard output.) In some cases logger raises exception from inside a logger method.
**My goal is say to logger not to write anything on to standard out/err, in case of any error at all.** All internal exception should be handled internally, and should be written into the log file.

---

**Details:**

My logger raised `charmap` error. This particular issue has been solved based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46636206/python-3-6-logging-modul-error-unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encod) thread.
But I afraid of that in a specific case, other exception can occur (file IO error, etc), on the field, which is very frustrating, that the logger fails, while the system works. I want to ensure that the logger don't print anything on standard out/err at all.

---

My expected behavior is something like this:

```
try:
    logger.debug('Some error maker')
except:
    try:
        logger.debug('Error during log')
    except:
        pass
```

Just, of course, I don't want to write try-except around all of my logger statement.

Is there anything similar feature in the logger? Something quiet mode?

Comment: you could put your try-except logic into a function?

Comment: The example code is the expected behavior, which want to be achieved using  some parameters of the logger.

Comment: i don't understand, maybe you can use a finally clause then `finally: logger.debug("This always logs")`

Comment: I don't want to write try-except around all of my logger statement. I search a parameter, which do this behavior automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a function like this?

```
def my_logger(thing_to_log):
    try:
        logger.debug(thing_to_log)
    except Exception:
        try:
            logger.debug('Error during log')
        except Exception:
            pass
```

In the rest of the code you'll only need:

```
my_logger(thing_to_log)
```

Answer (score 0):

To improve over @mdgm answer you can use the built-in features of `logging` to log stack trace and details of the exception:

```
def my_logger(thing_to_log):
    try:
        logger.debug(thing_to_log)
    except Exception:
        try:
            logger.debug('Error during log', exc_info=True, stack_info=True)
        except Exception:
            pass
```